# moderncv date year on top month

Tags: moderncv, cv, date

I am using the `moderncv` package to write my CV. If I put a date in a long format like this:

```
September 2014 - February 2015
```

the first column will be to wide to put enough content in the CV.

I have seen another example using an old template which uses something like this:

[image]

The example is from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Stefanqn/Bewerbung)

The problem is that I couldn't get how the year is placed on top of the month? Furthermore I would like to change the *.sty file to put in the date like in the given moderncv:

```
\cventry{month.year--month.year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
```

I would be glad if anybody could suggest an answer, because I couldn't find any solution at stackexchange.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to both parts of your queestion can be found (albeit in German) in the link you provided https://github.com/Stefanqn/Bewerbung.  This is a package (also on CTAN) which seems to adapt moderncv to German standards, one possibility would therefore be to attempt to use this package.

The below is a simplified version, based on the macros in the Brewerbung package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}

\def\dates[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\yearabove{\monthname[#1]}{#2}--\yearabove{\monthname[#3]}{#4}}
\newcommand{\yearabove}[2]{\parbox[t]{10mm}{\centering{#2\par\vspace{-2mm} \tiny{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\dates[09.2014-02.2015]
\end{document}
```

The lengths above may want some adjustment, but gives the below for your example
[image: Dates with month underneath]

As to changing the .sty file, in theory all that needs to change is that the first argument of `\cventry` (which is currently printed as is) gets passed to `\dates` but I have not tried this myself. Instead `\cventry{\dates[month.year-month.year]}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}` does work as desired.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I am used to programming languages like C, python etc. but the syntax of latex is sometimes hard to understand. The solution itself is simple and works as you suggested.