# how to create specific layout for year/month in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I`m trying to fix a problem related to a post already answered from you guys

[moderncv date year on top month](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310612/moderncv-date-year-on-top-month)

how can illustrate the date such as year and month in a cv like in the pics i uploaded?

using a moderncv template from this page
[Download Zip File for cv-template](https://www.timoschindler.de/moderne-vorlage-fuer-einen-lebenslauf-mit-lyx-latex/)

thx in advance!!

[image: status quo] [image: wanted]

**the solutions you guys provided worked well, big up!!!**

**i'm trying to edit the given problem a little bit more:**

**i wanna illustrate the date in the same way, except the the second date is the word "now" or in german language "Heute"**

**the picture beneath show my wanted result**

[image: wanted design]

my MWE looks like this, but i guess i gotta renewcommand sth. to get the result?!

[image]

```
\cventry{\dates[10.2014-Heute]}{Studium: Zahnmedizin}{Universität zu Köln}{}{Deutschland}{Abschlussziel: Dr. med. dent.; voraussichtlicher Abschluss: Frühjahr 2020}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal compilable code example (MWE, no link) here to help us help you. Maybe you should clarify which of the two layouts you want to achieve as well.

Comment: thx for your help, i'll keep that MWE in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310612/moderncv-date-year-on-top-month) that you linked. Using the new `\dates[]` command as the first argument to the `\cventry` command gives the output you're looking for, I think.

You can also use the `\yearabove` command to simply display two texts (like month and date) above each other. If the text is too long and creates a linebreak, it might be necessary to increase `\hintscolumnwidth`, the width of the date column (see the example).

You can also skip using the `\dates` command altogether and display German month names only using the `\yearabove` command (see the second `\cventry`).

Using the `\dates` command with arguments other than numbers (in the format `#1.#2-#3.#4`, where `#1`, `#3` are numbers) will result in errors, as the command expects numbers to convert them to the name of the month, i.e. `1` to `January`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} % options: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{grey}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310612/moderncv-date-year-on-top-month
\usepackage{datetime}
\def\dates[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\yearabove{\monthname[#1]}{#2}--\yearabove{\monthname[#3]}{#4}}
\newcommand{\yearabove}[2]{\parbox[t]{10mm}{\centering{#2\par\vspace{-2mm} \tiny{#1}}}}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % change the width of the column with the dates

\name{First}{Last}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Section}
\cventry{\dates[09.2014-02.2015]}{Title}{institution}{place}{}{Description.}

% the \yearabove command, which the \dates command uses internally, takes any two texts and displays one above the other
\cventry{\yearabove{mytext}{year}--\yearabove{mytext2}{year2}}{Title}{institution}{place}{}{Description.}

\cventry{\yearabove{Oktober}{2014}-- Heute}{Title}{institution}{place}{}{Description.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: hey chrisma, it acutally works, i trayed it the same way u did! i always have the problem that i'm writing an german document. see my next question please.

Comment: @JT_logic I've edited my answer to include your additional question

Comment: i really appreciate your work and time! everthing s fine and works well :)

Comment: @JT_logic Glad I could help. Would you like to accept the answer?